# Why can't I use a qt module purchased from the Qt Marketplace?

Tags: qt, qml, marketplace

I purchased Qt Pdf from the marketplace.  Included the module from the maintenance tool (QT 5.15.2). But still can't use it in my project. Why?

I am getting the error:

```
-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: pdf
```

when I include it in my project.

Here is the module

[image]

And here is the code

```
QT += pdf #:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have been using the MSVC compiler as the module does not work with mingw.

Comment: What does this mean ? Can you please elaborate ?